# Elastic Search getting the latest of each document by ID and language

Tags: elasticsearch

My company has a CMS and the visits to its content is logged to Elastic Search, each entry is a document like this:

```
{
  "datetime": "2020-08-02T17:12:54.012+01:00",
  "title" : "title of the content",
  "LocalNumber" : "000025",
  "CodeLanguage" : "eng"
}
```

There are more but these are the important ones. The `title` property changes over time meaning that the ID (the `LocalNumber`) is the same but the title may be different.

I'm trying to make an ES query to retrieve just the lastest document by `LocalNumber` and `CodeLanguage`. I could achieve doing it by `LocalNumber`, using field collapse:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "collapse": {
        "field": "LocalNumber.keyword"
    },
    "sort": [{"datetime": "desc"}]
}
```

How should I change this query to be able to get it by `LocalNumber` and `CodeLanguage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may as well aggregate by those two fields separately & then use `top_hits` to get only the latest doc:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_LocalNumber": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "LocalNumber.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": {
              "datetime": {
                "order": "desc"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "by_CodeLanguage": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "CodeLanguage.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": {
              "datetime": {
                "order": "desc"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And if you're interested in a subset of `LocalNumber` & `CodeLanguage`, you can constrain them in a `should` query.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may just use [second level of collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.8/collapse-search-results.html#second-level-of-collapsing) in `collapse`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "collapse": {
        "field": "LocalNumber.keyword",
        "inner_hits": {
            "name": "by lang",
            "collapse": {
                "field": "CodeLanguage.keyword"
            },
            "size": 3
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "datetime": "desc"
        }
    ]
}
```

This will return:

- 1 document per `LocalNumber.keyword`, most recent by `datetime` first (your original query);
- per each such document, up to 3 `inner_hits` documents per `CodeLanguage.keyword`.

With my test data it returns a result like the following:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "myindex2",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "datetime": "2020-08-02T17:12:54.012+01:00",
          "title": "title of the content 2",
          "LocalNumber": "000025",
          "CodeLanguage": "fr"
        },
        "fields": {
          "LocalNumber.keyword": [
            "000025"
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          1596384774012
        ],
        "inner_hits": {
          "by lang": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 4,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "myindex2",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "2",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "datetime": "2020-08-02T17:12:54.012+01:00",
                    "title": "title of the content 2",
                    "LocalNumber": "000025",
                    "CodeLanguage": "fr"
                  },
                  "fields": {
                    "CodeLanguage.keyword": [
                      "fr"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": "myindex2",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "10",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "datetime": "2020-08-01T17:12:54.012+01:00",
                    "title": "title of the content 10",
                    "LocalNumber": "000025",
                    "CodeLanguage": "eng"
                  },
                  "fields": {
                    "CodeLanguage.keyword": [
                      "eng"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I believe this is just a [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for normal Elasticsearch aggregations, like the one [joe posted above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63307159/5095957). So underneath ES will be doing the same thing, but this query is smaller and probably easier to understand.